# MySQL for WAMP is not starting. How to test MySQL and Apche

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

My WAMP is staying orange and not turning green. Been searching around on the web on how to troubleshoot. Basically it could be one or both of following issues:

- Apache is not starting
- MySQL is not starting.

It looks that the MySQL is not starting.
[Here is the screenshot](http://prntscr.com/dmg6et)
But I am little confused on what exactly is not working, because when I go to MySQL console, I can access database [here is console screenshot](http://prntscr.com/dmg8q1)
Also, the Apache is started/working shouldn't I be able to view Localhost, it doesn't relay on database access, but unfortunately I cant view Local host, I get "This localhost page can’t be found".
This is what MySQL log is showing:

```
2016-12-20T04:44:49.995569Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*3072 to 2*320 pages, LSN=2524895
2016-12-20T04:44:50.120568Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2016-12-20T04:44:50.167430Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=2524895
2016-12-20T04:54:05.892230Z 0 [Warning] wampmysqld64: Forcing close of thread 2  user: 'root'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It could be wamp and skype conflict. Try to resolve the same.

Comment: Check whether the port is used by some other apps

Comment: The first images says MYSQL is running as you are not offered the start/resume option on the menu

Comment: Being able to run the MYSQL Console also suggests that MYSQL is up and running

Comment: Orange Icon say One service is started, Looks like MYSQL is running and Apache is not

Comment: Do a Right click on `wampmanager icon` and then `Tools->Test Port 80` Then edit you question with the result of that

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there can be many reasons why WAMP stays orange.
For me it turned out to be, that some of the IIS components were on, once I unchecked them WAMP turned Green.
[image]